# Generate Numbers according to rules

Tags: php, arrays

I am stuck guys, i need to generate the numbers for each columns based on these rules:

a- only 5 numbers allowed per row

b- no repetition allowed per column

These are 6 tables each is 3X9. I randomly distributed zeros which means that the cell is locked and then i will distribute the numbers acrros the remaining cells and I manage to apply the first rule, any help with the second

```
//assign zero to all cells
$cardNumber = 0;
for($card=1;$card<=6;$card++){
    $cardNumber++;
    $tempCardNumber = array();   
    for($rowIndex=0;$rowIndex<3;$rowIndex++){
        for($columnIndex=0;$columnIndex<9;$columnIndex++){  
            $tempCardNumber[] = 0;                  
            $cardNumberArray[$cardNumber][$rowIndex][$columnIndex] = 0;
        }
    }
    $AllCardGenerate[$cardNumber] = $tempCardNumber;    
}

$cardNumber = 0;
//generate zeros
for($card=1;$card<=6;$card++){
    $cardNumber++;
    for($rowIndex=0;$rowIndex<3;$rowIndex++){
        $zerosGenerate = array();
        for($columnIndex=0;$columnIndex<9;$columnIndex++){                  
            $generatedIndex = rand(0,8);
            if(!in_array($generatedIndex, $zerosGenerate) && count($zerosGenerate)<5){
                $zerosGenerate[]  = $generatedIndex;
                $cardNumberArray[$cardNumber][$rowIndex][$generatedIndex] = 1;
            }else if(count($zerosGenerate)<5){
                $columnIndex--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Check the image for clarification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCJa0.png)
[image]

Comment: Please explain how "only 5 numbers allowed per row" will comply with a 3X9 table. (where there is room for nine numbers in a row)

Comment: BTW: I resized your image.... (made it a bit smaller...)

Comment: @Luuk it doesnt matter if they remain empty as long as the rules are applied on rows and columns .

Comment: @Luuk i have numbers from 1 till 90 must be distributed on 9 column and 18 rows so each row have 5 numbers then 5*18 = 90 which will distribute all the numbers as shown in the image but stuck to apply second rule

Comment: If you have unique number, please tell a bit more about the meaning of "no repetition allowed per column"

Comment: Show an example, no matter if it fails. The explanation why it failed will help understand the problem.

Comment: @Luuk as you can see from the image , each column have set of numbers ( 1-9,10-19,20-29,etc) that must distributed through the column, and the rows must online contain 5 out of 9 number. i added the code in which i distribute 1 and zeros where 0 is empty cell and 1 means it can hold  a number from the range which i can apply later but the main problem is to assign these 1's and 0's according to the mentioned rules

Answer (score 0):

(( I do not know how to hide the first part, until "EDIT:", but please skip tis first part, and start reading from "EDIT:" ))

You are saying you created a situation like this:

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

And now you need to fill in the columns.

If you look at the possible values for columns, you will see that the distribution is not correct. The first column has only 9 possibilities, the last column has 11 possibilities, and the other columns has 10 possibilities.

The first column should change from `1-9` to `1-10`, the 2nd to `11-20`, the 3rd to `21-30`, ..... up to `81-90`.

So, this should fill in the numbers (and do some formatting for SO):

```
$j=1;
for($i=0;$i<9; $i++){
    $nrs[$i]=$j;
    $j=$j+10;
}
for($card=1;$card<=6;$card++){
    print "|1 to 10|11 to 20|21 to 30|31 to 40|41 to 50|51 to 60| 61 to 70|71 to 80| 81 to 90|\n";
    print "|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|\n";
    for($rowIndex=0;$rowIndex<3;$rowIndex++){
        print "|";
        for($columnIndex=0;$columnIndex<9;$columnIndex++){   
            if ($cardNumberArray[$card][$rowIndex][$columnIndex]==1) {
                $cardNumberArray[$card][$rowIndex][$columnIndex] = $nrs[$columnIndex]++;
             }               
           print $cardNumberArray[$card][$rowIndex][$columnIndex]."|";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

result:

| 1 to 10 | 11 to 20 | 21 to 30 | 31 to 40 | 41 to 50 | 51 to 60 | 61 to 70 | 71 to 80 | 81 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 31 | 41 | 51 | 0 | 71 | 81 |
| 0 | 11 | 0 | 32 | 0 | 0 | 61 | 72 | 82 |
| 1 | 0 | 21 | 33 | 42 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 83 |

| 1 to 10 | 11 to 20 | 21 to 30 | 31 to 40 | 41 to 50 | 51 to 60 | 61 to 70 | 71 to 80 | 81 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 12 | 0 | 34 | 43 | 0 | 0 | 73 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 22 | 35 | 44 | 52 | 0 | 74 | 0 |
| 0 | 13 | 0 | 36 | 45 | 53 | 0 | 0 | 84 |

| 1 to 10 | 11 to 20 | 21 to 30 | 31 to 40 | 41 to 50 | 51 to 60 | 61 to 70 | 71 to 80 | 81 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 14 | 0 | 37 | 46 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 85 |
| 0 | 15 | 0 | 38 | 47 | 0 | 0 | 75 | 86 |
| 4 | 16 | 0 | 0 | 48 | 0 | 62 | 0 | 87 |

| 1 to 10 | 11 to 20 | 21 to 30 | 31 to 40 | 41 to 50 | 51 to 60 | 61 to 70 | 71 to 80 | 81 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 0 | 23 | 0 | 49 | 0 | 63 | 0 | 88 |
| 0 | 17 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 54 | 0 | 76 | 89 |
| 0 | 18 | 0 | 0 | 50 | 55 | 64 | 0 | 90 |

| 1 to 10 | 11 to 20 | 21 to 30 | 31 to 40 | 41 to 50 | 51 to 60 | 61 to 70 | 71 to 80 | 81 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 0 | 25 | 39 | 51 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 91 |
| 7 | 0 | 26 | 40 | 0 | 56 | 0 | 77 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 27 | 41 | 0 | 57 | 65 | 0 | 0 |

| 1 to 10 | 11 to 20 | 21 to 30 | 31 to 40 | 41 to 50 | 51 to 60 | 61 to 70 | 71 to 80 | 81 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 19 | 28 | 0 | 52 | 58 | 0 | 0 | 92 |
| 0 | 20 | 29 | 42 | 53 | 0 | 66 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 30 | 0 | 54 | 59 | 0 | 0 | 93 |

Some columns have to much `1`'s in them like the 4th one, because it increment to values above the allowed 40.

But that is a problem in your code, which I did not touch.

I am still wondering what you mean by the second rule "no repetition allowed per column"

#######################################################################

EDIT:

- Distribute 1's and 0's such that:

  - Count of 1's in each row = 5
  - count of 1's in column is 0 for column 9,
  - count of 1's in column is 8 for column 11,
  - count of 1's in column is 10.

code:

```
for($i=0;$i<9; $i++){
    $nrs[$i]= $i==0 ? 9 : ( $i==8 ? 11 : 10 );
}
$rowcount = 5;

for($card=1;$card<=6;$card++){
    print "|1 to 9|10 to 19|20 to 29|30 to 39|40 to 49|50 to 59| 60 to 69|70 to 79| 80 to 90|\n";
    print "|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|\n";
    for($rowIndex=0;$rowIndex<3;$rowIndex++){
        print "|";
        for($columnIndex=0;$columnIndex<9;$columnIndex++){                  
            if ($rowcount>0 && $nrs[$columnIndex]>0) {
                $rowcount--;
                $nrs[$columnIndex]--;
                $cardNumberArray[$card][$rowIndex][$columnIndex] = 1; //$rowcount*100+$nrs[$columnIndex];
            }
           print $cardNumberArray[$card][$rowIndex][$columnIndex]."|";
        }
        $rowcount=5;
        print "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

output:

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

| 1 to 9 | 10 to 19 | 20 to 29 | 30 to 39 | 40 to 49 | 50 to 59 | 60 to 69 | 70 to 79 | 80 to 90 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

This, sort of, proves that your problem is not solvable.

The last rows only have 4 time a 1 because in the other column's a 1 is no longer possible because the total number of 1's in that column is already used.

Making it fancier, by randomizing the position of the 1's, will  not change anything to this.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i guess i am closer to the solution, The range of the column is fixed by the client in which first column is from 1-9 and last 80 to 90 which calibrate each other on average. .
what i meant by "no repetition allowed per column" is that for example column 2 range is from 10 till 19 and these numbers must be randomly distributed through the column without repetition.

Comment: I know how to distribute the numbers but i need to create the first situtation you added which is the table with 1's and zero's in way i have five 1's in each row, 9 1's in the first column, 11 1's in the last column and 10 1's in the rest of the columns

Comment: I keep saying: `I am still wondering what you mean by the second rule "no repetition allowed per column"`

Comment: forget all the above. I just want to distribute 1's and 0's such that:
- Count of 1's in each row = 5
- count of 1's in each column is 9 for column 0, 11 for column 8 and 10 for the rest of columns

Comment: I added and EDIT..    This must be the longest answer I have ever (and will ever be giving.... )

Comment: Thanks for your contribution i really appreciate it